# Responsive web design - ensuring height of adjacent div stays the same using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am currently creating a responsive webpage using **2 columns** (using 2 `<div>`s + CSS of `float: left;`) elements which becomes **1 column** using a media query (i.e. `@media`) when the width of the browser becomes less than **480px** (i.e. on mobile displays).

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

  <div class="col-half info">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-half contact">
    <h1>Get in touch</h1>
    <a href="mailto:info@somesite.com">info@somesite.com</a>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Everything works nicely, however at **490px** the following happens ...

[image: DIV elements at different heights]

Ideally the DIV on the right hand side should increase in height (so both DIV's are aligned at the same height) as the browser window get's resized but not using JavaScript (as some forums suggest).

I've hit a brick wall with this and don't see a clear solution, any help is appreciated!

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#container {
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
}

div.col-half {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 25px;
  float: left; 
  min-height: 200px;
}

div.clear { clear: both;  }
.info     { background-color: #A95563; }
.contact  { background-color: #A9718A; }

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
 div.col-half {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
 } 
}
```

**CodePen**

http://codepen.io/bobmarksie/pen/ONyojM

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: have you considered using display:flex in container div?

Comment: Just added `display:flex;` to the `div#container` CSS and it seems to work well.  However, the height became `500px`.  Should I just create another wrapper `<div>` (with height of `200px`) around the `<div class="col-half">` ?  If so, will it be responsive?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXYaZz?editors=0100 is this a desirable result?

Comment: @silviagreen - not quite i.e. the `min-height` of the container is `500px` whereas I want want the min-height of the 2 cols to be `200px`.  Not far away though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following lines to your #container css:

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXYaxq)

Comment: Remove min-height:500px and you're in business.

Comment: I know it looks better.. But what if they want it as min-height? Well I'm going to add your advice on the pen anyway, thanks;

Comment: It could go either way. I think if you're going to give it a height, you should add `align-items:center`, but that's just my personal taste.

Comment: Yep, this is the business.  Need to read up on **flex** in general. Thanks for your time!

Comment: 3 flex attributes important to **sizing**: [**flex property**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp), [**flex direction**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp), [**flex wrap**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp); 3 flex attributes important to **align**: [**align items**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp) vertical align , [**justify content**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) horizontal align, [**align content**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-content.asp) multiline align;

Comment: with **sizing** I meant **sizing/positioning**

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` on your container div:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

div#container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    
    display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
    display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
    display: flex;
}

div.col-half {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 25px;
    float: left;
}

div.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.info {
    background-color: #A95563;
}

.contact {
    background-color: #A9718A;
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    div.col-half {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container">
    <div class="col-half info">
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-half contact">
        <h1>Get in touch</h1>
        <a href="mailto:info@somesite.com">info@somesite.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be responsive (I clicked the "Full page" button) when I resize my browser window less than 480px width.

Comment: Try it now with the vendor prefix fallbacks added.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with table also.

```
.container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.container .col-half {
  display: table-cell;
  min-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Don't use float with this.